# Python. [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом. Как закрыть процесс?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Пытаюсь удалить объект модели с файлом относящимся к нему и получаю ошибку -

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к
> файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом...

Просмотрел много статей и пока не нашел решения проблемы. Как я понял необходимо найти номер процесса и закрыть его, но основная загвоздка в том, что я не могу найти этот номер процесса. Удалить пытаюсь аудио файл, как найти процесс, что бы выполнить `os.close(fd)` или может есть еще вариации закрытия процесса?

Моя модель:

```
class Audio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    author_track = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    title_track = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    audio = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path_audio, content_types=['audio/mpeg'], max_upload_size=52428800,
        blank=True, null=True
    )

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.audio.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Как дополнить метод Delete, что бы он закрывал файл перед удалением?

Comment: self.audio.close()?

Comment: К сожалению так не работает, пробовал уже